# .NET entering numbers into NumericUpDown isn't working

Tags: .net, maxscript

I'm seeing an odd issue with the NumericUpDown. Could be related to the language being used as I'm calling .net via Max Script in 3DS Max but I'm not sure. Once the control is added I can only enter values directly into the type in box using the keyboard numpad. The alpha numeric keys don't work at all and even stranger several numbers don't work on the numpad either, 2,4,6,8 don't do anything at all.

The code sample will make little sense to anyone that hasn't used Max with .net. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
dn=dotNetObject "numericUpDown"
```

Comment: Numeric keypad has two modes. In first mode you enter numbers, and in second mode instead of numbers the numeric keys take the roles of arrow keys, and also, Home/End/PgUp/PgDn keys. You switch the mode with Num Lock key, which on some keyboards is not marked as "Num Lock" but as a number 1 in a square.

Comment: Thanks but none of that has any affect what so ever. I'm going to write my own instead. I have the feeling it has some thing to do with the fact that this is a hybrid Max Script implementation of .NET and not pure C#. If I could I would be using Py and QT but this tool goes back years and it would take to long to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. In 3DS Max you need to set EnableAccelerators=false when you click on the control. Setting to false disables Max's key inputs. I had it in the code but it was running before it was clicked on and was being set back to true.